# Javascript - build array in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to populate an array from a JSON feed. My code looks something like this:

```
// multiple arrays
var linje_1 = []
var linje_2 = []

// loop from json feed to populate array

for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // I'm trying to "build" the array here. I know for sure that data[i] is good value that match the suffix of the array.
    arrayname = 'linje_'+data[i]; 
    arrayname.push({ label: data[i].x_+''+sid[a]+'', y: data[i].y_+''+sid[a]+'' })
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve the above?

The problem is that the code will not accept `arrayname`, but if I change and hardcode `linje_1`, everything works as expected.

Comment: You're pushing data to a String... 'linje_1'

Answer (score 3):

When you define a variable `arrayname = 'linje_'+data[i];` then its type is String. Strings are not arrays, you can't treat them like array, they don't have array methods.

If you want to dynamically construct the name of the variable, the best thing you can do is to use object and its keys:

```
var lines = {
    linje_1: [],
    linje_2: []
};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var arrayname = 'linje_' + data[i]; 
    lines[arrayname].push({ label: data[i].x_ + sid[a], y: data[i].y_ + sid[a]});
}
```

Also note, that I cleaned up the code a little (things like `data[i].x_ + '' + sid[a] + ''`).

Comment: I find this one much cleaner than using `window` (or a worse possibility, `this`.)  I wrote an almost identical version, but was beat to it by a minute.  (Mine differed only in inlining the `arrayname` variable where it's used.)

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing data to a String, not an array. Try this:

```
 window[arrayname].push(/* ... */);
```

if your variables are declared in the scope of the window, they can be referenced in multiple manners:

```
myArray
window.myArray
window['myArray'] // You want this one
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same variable for an array and string.

```
arrayname = 'linje_'+data[i]; 
arrayname.push({ label: data[i].x_+''+sid[a]+'', y: data[i].y_+''+sid[a]+'' })
```

The variable `arrayname` is defined as a string, but then you call the `push` method which is only a method for arrays.